# DbMigration in ef code first 4.4

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

we are using ef code first 4.4 with db migrations. I have an entity called Paypal in our `DbContext`. When I run the `Update-Database` command from package manager console, it generates the db but then throws exception with message

```
There is already an object named 'PayPal' in the database.
```

When I inspected the sql statements in package manager console using verbose command, there were two commands for creating paypal table, one from InitialCreate.cs in Migrations folder and other from test.cs in the same folder.

**Edit 1:**
The `Up` method in both `DateTime_InitialCreate.cs` and `DateTime_test.cs` contain following first entry.

```
CreateTable(
                "dbo.PayPal",
                c => new
                    {
                        Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                        ActionUrl = c.String(),
                        Cmd = c.String(),
                        Price = c.String(),
                        Interval = c.String(),
                        IntervalType = c.String(),
                        AutoRecurring = c.String(),
                        Business = c.String(),
                        Return = c.String(),
                        CancelUrl = c.String(),
                        NotifyUrl = c.String(),
                        PlanName = c.String(),
                        Amount = c.String(),
                        CurrencyCode = c.String(),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);
```

When inspecting the code, the both files seem identical with no difference at all.

What should I do to solve this issue?

Comment: Can you please show us some code? What does the InitialCreate.cs look like? What does test.cs look like? Thanks.

Comment: huge files more than 900 lines each :(

Comment: let me know if you need something else to figure out the problem plz

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading this correctly (and correct me if I'm wrong), you are trying to create the table in both locations without checking if it already exists. In which case, when you run Update-Database, it's trying to create it twice because it finds it in both files. At which point you're getting an error for it already being there.

You need to put in a check to make sure the table doesn't already exist into both files to prevent this from happening.

Let me know if I'm reading this wrong.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know enough about code first and migrations. I even confess that I have no idea if the code in Initializer.cs and test.cs is autogenrated based on changes in our model or we create it manually but I guess it is auto generated?

Comment: I presume this because a migration folder is automatically created in the project when we run enable-migration command from package manager console.